# Getting the latest value in the cell used from specified "forecast" column

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to read the latest value from column "forecast" (BM) till column D, I have written below code but it is not giving me the right value.
For example I have latest value in column AV21- 0.5 as my result.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Column <> 9 Then Exit Sub
    Dim foundCell As Range:  Set foundCell = Cells(Target.Row, "I").End(xlToLeft)
    Target.Offset(, 1).Value = foundCell.Value
    Target.Offset(, 2).Value = Cells(1, foundCell.Column).Value
End Sub
Public Sub LoopCells()

Dim c As Range
Dim rngSearch As Range
Dim rngFind As Range
 Set rngFind = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:K15")

For Each c In rngFind
    If c.Value = "Forecast" Then
      MsgBox "FindMe found at " & c.Address
      
      Set rngSearch = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:" & c.Address)
      
      'Set LastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
      
      ' MsgBox LastCell
     Dim d As Range

For Each d In rngSearch 'Range("strFirstAddress:A1").Cells
  If d.Value > 0 Then
    
    MsgBox foundCell
   
    
    Exit For
  End If
Next

MsgBox foundCell
MsgBox "The first value greater than zero is in cell " & firstAddress & _
       "; - it has value " & firstValue
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

[image: example1]

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your post; you're getting the right answer?  Your image does not show row numbers, so I can only make assumptions (regarding the value "0.5" being on row 21 with a cost of $5,736).  Can you update for clarity on intention?  It almost seems like you're just need `set foundCell = .cells(x,"BM").end(xltoLeft)`.

Comment: Hi , Please find the image below. I am getting the forecast column but from that column i wanted to read till column D or A and get the value used which is >0 . I am getting the output as "Group" but intsead i wanted to get the value AV21 and i.e.., 0.5

Comment: `AV21` is October 31 (check your month labels), which is not what I would expect to be the latest/last; I would expect `AX21`, November 13, to be the last data entered/most recent... which is why I expected `set foundCell = .cells(x,"BM").end(xltoLeft)` to be useful.  How are you choosing your "latest" information?

Comment: Yes correct i agree, sorry it should be AX21.. should i give cell address in "BM"? What you mentioned above? Also can I get the week number cell also if possible? This week number will be dynamic

Comment: Yes, you can use the `cells(1,foundCell.Column).Value`; this is based on the above `foundCell` language, where you would either loop through the cells or put a direct value in for `x`.

Comment: I would recommend putting a check that the column being referenced is A) a number and B) is not less than the table you want to refer.

Comment: Hi Cyril , but my forecast column "BM" is not constant ?

Comment: You can dynamically find where "forecast" via `rows(3).find("forecast")` and work from there to define the column where you want to move left from.

Comment: Hi Cyril , i have written the explicit as you said and i am trying to show it in Msgbox it says variable not found error . Can you please let me know where should i write the code exactly. Please find my code re-written in my question . i am stuck with object defined or variable defined errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick example that may help (based on `beforeDoubleClick`, but should indicate how to utilize the `foundCell`):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Column <> 9 Then Exit Sub
    Dim foundCell As Range:  Set foundCell = Cells(Target.Row, "I").End(xlToLeft)
    Target.Offset(, 1).Value = foundCell.Value
    Target.Offset(, 2).Value = Cells(1, foundCell.Column).Value
End Sub
```

Testing info:
[image]

Note that "I" is column 9, where I just wanted a quick check of not wanting to start running if I accidentally double click elsewhere.